# Update label properties of table view cell dependant upon data

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

So I have a custom table view cell which I have designed in its own xib, containing a few labels and images.

I'm trying to update the background colour of one of these labels depending upon the text given to the label & give it rounded edges.

I'm trying this for the edges with the following code, however it does not work and i'm not sure where this code needs to be for it to update each cell as it scrolls.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CardCell";
    CardTableViewCell *cell = (CardTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        //cell = [[CardTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"CardCell"];
        cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"CardCell" owner:self options:nil]objectAtIndex:0];

    }

    // Configure the cell...
    NSManagedObject *card = [self.cards objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.cardName setText:[card valueForKey:@"name"]];
    [cell.type setText:[card valueForKey:@"attribute"]];
    [cell.attack setText:[card valueForKey:@"attack"]];
    [cell.defense setText:[card valueForKey:@"defense"]];
    [cell.species setText:[card valueForKey:@"species"]];
    [cell.starLevel setText:[card valueForKey:@"stars"]];
    cell.type.layer.cornerRadius = cell.type.bounds.size.height / 8;


    UIImage *cardImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[card valueForKey:@"thumb"]];
    [cell.cardImage setImage:cardImage];

    return (UITableViewCell *)cell;
}
```

The text and card image display correctly.

Comment: " it does not work" can you elaborate whats not working ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cell has no frame in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, therefore the corner radius is not set. 
In this case, you should set the corner radius in `willDisplayCell`.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (yourCellShouldHaveRoundedCorners) {
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = cell.bounds.size.height / 8;
    }
}
```

The background color of the label should work in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Also, I see that you set a lot of properties on the cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` (i.e. type, attack, defense and so on). Since you already have a custom cell, it would be better to create an `NSManagedObject` property on the cell, and set all these properties on the setter of this object.

This way, you will only have to call `cell.managedObject = card` and the setter will furher set the other properties.

This approach is more model-oriented and it can save you some code duplication.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use fixed number as **cell.type.bounds.size.height** won't render to a correct value in cellForRowAt

```
 cell.type.layer.cornerRadius = 10 ;

 cell.type.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

OR add this to cell class

```
 -(void)layoutSubviews
 {
     self.type.layer.cornerRadius = self.type.bounds.size.height / 8;
 }
```

Regarding color it will work perfectly in **cellForRowAt** like that

```
 if(yourLogic)
 {
    cell.type.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

 }
 else
 {
    cell.type.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
 }
```

Comment: This worked a treat! thanks for that.
Obviously in hindsight that wouldnt work as the cell hasnt rendered yet so the label does not have a height.